# Manage versions with SVN

Tags: svn, release-management

We have a project on SVN, on each commit we add to comments the Jira version we are fixing. On each Release build (with Jenkins) we want to take from SVN all comments just after the previous Release build and create the Release Notes with the Jiras mentioned on comments.(we already have the way to do that)
We do create a Tag always for each Release versions.

Problem to solve: we need to have some markup to the previous build on svn.

One solution would be to go to latest tag, get the top revision number(tag-creation), come back to trunk, and get all commits just after the tag-creation commit.

But.. we would like to have this Release markup visible on the trunk logs, so with a simple look to svn logs we can see from where to where a Release goes... 
for that the only way we found is to commit a fake file just to have the revision comment as "build version ###".

any suggestions to do it in a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of additional commit of file-list you can:

**Pure-SVN Way**

- create (any) *conventional* property in `/trunk` with the value "Revision of last release"
- propget before and propset|propedit+commit property-change after each release

**Mercurial+HGSubversion Way**

(somehow *lazier*)

- Maintain RO clone of Subversion repo
- After each release pull from upstream-SVN changes (not needed in dev-round) and get changelog (in Mercurial) with easy revset+template, no any actions on SVN side at all

**PS:** I can write this regexp for you easy, dirty draft as example for well-tagged repo

```
>hg log -r "last(last(tag(),2)):first(last(tag(),2))"
1365:1.8.4
1366:
1367:
1368:
1369:
1370:1.8.5
```

this is pure HG-tags, for properly cloned SVN-repo it will be usable too (SVN-tags will be HG-tags)